# Why Rich file manager insert filemanager.config.json instead of insert image to text field

Tags: javascript, json, file-management, ckeditor4.x

I've used Rich file manager with Laravel5.3.20 as the default configuration as below

Javascript

```
 <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea', {
            filebrowserBrowseUrl: '{!! url('gallery/index.html') !!}',
            ///ImageBrowser : true,
            autoUpdateElement:true,
            language:'en'
        });
    </script>
```

Images in textarea url is wrong.

```
<p><img alt="" src="http://website.dev/gallery/connectors/php/filemanager.php?mode=readfile&amp;path=%2Fae.jpg&amp;config=filemanager.config.json&amp;time=1477642950519" style="height:960px; width:720px" /></p>
```

All files, folder and sub folder have already update to **userfiles**
But it image url which i have to insert into Database with textarea go wrong as above url.

FileManager.configure.json

```
{
    "_comment": "IMPORTANT : go to the wiki page to know about options configuration https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager/wiki/Filemanager-configuration-file",
    "options": {
        "culture": "en",
        "lang": "php",
        "theme": "flat-dark",
        "defaultViewMode": "grid",
        "localizeGUI": true,
        "showFullPath": false,
        "showTitleAttr": false,
        "browseOnly": false,
        "showConfirmation": true,
        "showThumbs": true,
        "searchBox": true,
        "listFiles": true,
        "fileSorting": "NAME_ASC",
        "folderPosition": "bottom",
        "quickSelect": false,
        "charsLatinOnly": false,
        "splitterWidth": 200,
        "splitterMinWidth": 200,
        "dateFormat": "d M Y H:i",
        "serverRoot": true,
        "fileRoot": false,
        "fileConnector": false,
        "fileRootSizeLimit": false,
        "baseUrl": false,
        "capabilities": ["select", "upload", "download", "rename", "move", "replace", "delete"],
        "logger": false,
        "plugins": []
    },
    "security": {
        "allowFolderDownload": false,
        "allowChangeExtensions": false,
        "allowNoExtension": false,
        "normalizeFilename": true,
        "uploadPolicy": "DISALLOW_ALL",
        "uploadRestrictions": [
            "jpg",
            "jpe",
            "jpeg",
            "gif",
            "png",
            "svg",
            "txt",
            "pdf",
            "odp",
            "ods",
            "odt",
            "rtf",
            "doc",
            "docx",
            "xls",
            "xlsx",
            "ppt",
            "pptx",
            "csv",
            "ogv",
            "avi",
            "mkv",
            "mp4",
            "webm",
            "m4v",
            "ogg",
            "mp3",
            "wav",
            "zip",
            "rar"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": {
        "unallowed_files": [
            ".htaccess",
            "web.config"
        ],
        "unallowed_dirs": [
            "_thumbs",
            ".CDN_ACCESS_LOGS",
            "cloudservers"
        ],
        "unallowed_files_REGEXP": "/^\\./",
        "unallowed_dirs_REGEXP": "/^\\./"
    },
    "upload": {
        "multiple": true,
        "paramName": "files",
        "chunkSize": false,
        "numberOfFiles": 5,
        "fileSizeLimit": 16000000,
        "overwrite": false,
        "imagesOnly": false
    },
    "images": {
        "imagesExt": [
            "jpg",
            "jpe",
            "jpeg",
            "gif",
            "png",
            "svg"
        ],
        "main": {
            "autoOrient": true,
            "maxWidth": 1280,
            "maxHeight": 1024
        },
        "thumbnail": {
            "enabled": true,
            "cache": true,
            "dir": "_thumbs/",
            "crop": true,
            "maxWidth": 64,
            "maxHeight": 64
        }
    },
    "videos": {
        "showVideoPlayer": true,
        "videosExt": [
            "ogv",
            "mp4",
            "webm",
            "m4v"
        ],
        "videosPlayerWidth": 400,
        "videosPlayerHeight": 222
    },
    "audios": {
        "showAudioPlayer": true,
        "audiosExt": [
            "ogg",
            "mp3",
            "wav"
        ]
    },
    "pdfs": {
        "showPdfReader": true,
        "pdfsExt": [
            "pdf",
            "odt",
            "odp",
            "ods"
        ],
        "pdfsReaderWidth": "640",
        "pdfsReaderHeight": "480"
    },
    "docs": {
        "showGoogleViewer": true,
        "docsExt": [
            "doc",
            "docx",
            "xls",
            "xlsx",
            "ppt",
            "pptx"
        ],
        "docsReaderWidth": "640",
        "docsReaderHeight": "480"
    },
    "edit": {
        "enabled": true,
        "lineNumbers": true,
        "lineWrapping": true,
        "codeHighlight": false,
        "theme": "elegant",
        "editExt": [
            "txt",
            "csv"
        ]
    },
    "customScrollbar": {
        "enabled": true,
        "theme": "inset-2-dark",
        "button": true
    },
    "extras": {
        "extra_js": [],
        "extra_js_async": true
    },
    "icons": {
        "path": "images/fileicons/",
        "folder": "_Open.png",
        "parent": "_Parent.png",
        "default": "default.png"
    },
    "url": "https://github.com/servocoder/RichFilemanager",
    "version": "1.0.6"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version that you use doesn't support absolute paths in preview links, it builds preview urls via connector request path only.It was done because some users keep connector file separate from the client-side scripts (different servers and so on). After some discussions it was decided to support both options: absolute path (by default) and connector path (configurable). The feature that you need will be included in the next major release 2.0. Some discussion on your problem is [here](https://github.com/servocoder/RichFilemanager/issues/58).